# Bootstrap: Overlap for col-auto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The following code leads to this outcome:
[image]

Anyone knows, how I can avoid the overlap effect when using col-auto?

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col">

    {# Title #}
    <h4 class="mb-0">Tickets:</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    Ticket 1, Ticket 2, Ticket 3, [...]
  </div>
</div> {# / .row #}
```

Comment: Do you really need `col-auto`? In my opinion, using flexboxes is a better way.

Comment: What css do you have applied? This columns are suppose to stay within you `row`